# Android, Send SMS in JSON format

Tags: android, json, sms

Is it possible to convert `JSONObject` to `String` and send via SMS ? Or even can I sen `JSONObject` directly via SMS?

Comment: `JSONObject.toString();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Easy way is Convert your messge object to string and send

```
MsgSend m = new MsgSend();
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(m);
sendSMS(number, jsonString);
public static void sendSMS(String phoneNmbr, String message)
 {

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNmbr, null, message, null, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SMS is just a string ,no matter in what format.

Get the string result of the `JSONObject` and send it.

But you should take care of its content length,if it is too long,split the message and send part of it each time.